# VLC player logo stays at task bar even after closing!

Tags: video, vlc, taskbar

Most of the time after watching a video while I am closing the VLC player, there always is a task stays in the task manager and task bar, I can't play any video until I manually kills it from task manager. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Ah, let me see.  Me Rpi4B buster 2019sep26.  Just now I did this: (1) opened VLC, (2) played a short mp4 file, (3) closed VLC.  (A) The VLC task icon on the top task bar disappeared.  Nothing unusual.

Answer (score 1):

To disable vlc from running in the background, do this:
VLC --> Tools --> Preferences --> Deselect "Show systray icon".